# Adding dynamic row to ngTable not displaying

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, html-table, ngtable

I have created an application with ngTable using grouping functionality, The application is working fine but the problem is that when I add dynamic data (rows) to the table, its not reflecting dynamically, unless or otherwise when we click the table title for sorting or when we click the pagination

I have recreated the problem within a plunker, there you can find a button, when clicked one Dynamic row is added but not reflecting within the table

**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/ni0d114GQHGTNAg1N4vk?p=preview)**

```
  <body ng-app="main" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
  <button ng-click="addDynamicDatas()">Add Datas</button>
    <table ng-table="tableParamsOne" class="table">
      <tbody ng-repeat="group in $groups">
        <tr class="ng-table-group" ng-hide="group.data[0].role==='None'">
          <td>
              <strong>{{ group.value }}</strong>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="user in group.data">
          <td sortable="name" data-title="'Name'">
               <span ng-class="{'bold-text': user.role=='None'}" ng-show="user.role==='None'"> {{user.name}}</span>
            </td>
          <td sortable="age" data-title="'Age'">
                {{user.age}}
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
```

add function

```
$scope.addDynamicDatas = function()
{
   $scope.myDataOne.push({name: "Abcd", age: 10, role: 'Administrator'});
}
```

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably not an ideal solution but is the only one that I could find.

You can add `$scope.tableParamsOne.reload();` after you update your array.

Also currently when your grid is updating when you click a header it is not updating the amount of pages in the pagination. To solve this you can add `$scope.tableParamsOne.total($scope.myDataOne.length);`

Answer (score 0):

I am also using ng-table(@4.0.0) to make local/client-side insertion/deletion after a successful server submit and got the similar problem of update ng-table. @Bradley's answer above does not work directly. So I chased the source code and found that the reload() called the getData(). After insert a row into the target rowset (`ctrl.tbContents.rows` in my case), I have to add bellow line in my`tbParams` definition to make `ctrl.tbParams.reload()` work:

```
getData: function() {
  return ngTableDefaultGetData(ctrl.tbContents.rows, ctrl.tbParams);
}
```

Note to inject the `ngTableDefaultGetData`.